# Can we generate JAXB classes for a set of xsd in multiple packages?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

I have an xsd which has **several child XSD** s embedded (using "xsd:include".) in it (but each xsd belongs to the **same namespace**). I was asked to generate jaxb classes in **separate sub packages** (one sub package per each child XSD) instead of one package.

According to what I have read so far, we can add `jaxb:schemaBindings` to these separate xsds and generate the classes in separate packages, if only those xsds belong to **different namespaces**.

But in my case, what I want to do is to create classes in several sub packages for a set of xsds belong to the **same namespace**. Could you please help me to do this using JAXB?

---

**Edit:** I have added little more description about my problem to clarify it little bit more.

All of my XSDs has following header. Therefore **same namespace**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:srm="http://www.mycompany.com/srm/"
    targetNamespace="http://www.mycompany.com/srm/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.0" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">
```

Let's say my schema file names are A.xsd, B.xsd, and C.xsd.

- In C.xsd, I have defined some elements (string type) with above mentioned header.
- In B.xsd, I have included C.xsd using "xsd:include" tag, then there is a complexType definition using the complex types defined in C.xsd.(Has the same header I have mentioned above)
- In A.xsd, I have included B.xsd using "xsd:include" tag, then there is a complexType definition using the complex types defined in B.xsd.(Has the same header I have mentioned above)

I want to generate JAXB classes like I have mentioned below.

- The JAXB classes related to A.xsd to generate in com.generate.packageA package.
- The JAXB classes related to B.xsd to generate in com.generate.packageB package.
- The JAXB classes related to C.xsd to generate in com.generate.packageC package.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?  I am trying to implement something similar and was hoping there was a solution

Answer (score 3):

You could generate JAXB classes from each of the "included" schemas separately into separate packages and leverage the episode mechanism available in the XJC tool.

**Examples (from answers given on Stack Overflow)**

- [What is an .episode file..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756185/what-is-an-episode-file/9757472#9757472)
- [How to make two XSDs to use the same custom object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701141/how-to-make-two-xsds-to-use-the-same-custom-object/8704129#8704129)
- [Can Castor handle class generation from multiple XSDs importing from a base XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986082/can-castor-handle-class-generation-from-multiple-xsds-importing-from-a-base-xsd/7986486#7986486)

Comment: Hi @Blaise Doughan, Thanks for your quick response, But as I understand, all of above links are linked with using multiple namespaces in multiple xsds. May be I have missing something, could you please check the edit I have done to my post and give me some idea about this? thanks.

Comment: I tried to use .episode file. But it didn't generate any classes when I used the previously created .episode file(using C.xsd) to generate classes for B.xsd. It didn't even give me an error.